# How do I include a Jetpack Navigation graph from a compiled library (aar) into my app?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a library that I have deployed to a maven repo. This library does not define any activities, only fragments. Additionally, the library defines a navigation graph. How would I use this graph from an application?

From my testing, I can define this graph in the app's nav graph definition(and the editor does not complain that it cannot resolve the resource):

```xml
    <include app:graph="@navigation/my_library_graph" />
```

However, when I build I end up with the following error:

```
Referenced navigation file with navigationXmlId = my_library_graph not found
```

I would like to note that the library project includes a sample application module that works by simply including the library's nav graph into the app's nav graph.

Comment: Can you add your library link so I can test it?

Comment: @IslamAssem sorry, I don't have a sample readily available, but did find that this is an open issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184874605

Comment: The example you sent is for the different issue but I tried to reproduce your issue but the app worked, so it would be better if you share your library or an example with issue

Comment: @IslamAssem Oh, right. The title says for deep links but the reproduction steps are identical. The nuanced issue is that this will work if the module is in the same project(even if the module isn't included in the app--bizarre), but not if it is a compiled AAR from a different project altogether